# Azure pipeline self hosted agent demands Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a job that needs Windows if there are any NuGet packages because the `PushSymbols` task doesn't work on Linux

```
jobs:
- job: 'The job'
  pool:
    #${{ if eq(variables.useSelfHostedAgent, 'True') }}: # is ignored
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      name: 'Default' # run on rwb's machine (plus whatever else is in the default pool).
      ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
        demands: 
        - Agent.OS -equals 'Windows_NT' # PushSymbols task in pack.yml only works on Windows.
    ${{ else }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # run on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).
```

I think that I have such an agent...
[image]

.. but Azure doesn't.

```
##[error]No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the following demand: Agent.OS. All demands: Agent.OS -equals 'Windows_NT', Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1
Pool: Default
Started: Just now
Duration: 1m 12s
```

What's wrong with it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I will meet the issue if I add '' in 'Windows_NT'.
[image]

However, if I remove the '' in 'Windows_NT' and let it like belows, the issue gone.

```
demands: 
- Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT
```

Please kindly try whether it works on your side.
Also FYI, the job name in `- job: 'The job'` is invalid as it is supposed to not have the symbols like space.

Comment: That's it: remove the quotes. When is a string not a string?

Comment: Hi @RichardBarraclough, from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines) you could see the official example after the -equals doesn't contain '' and tells if the pool name has space then you could use ''. So I guess '' will impact the recognition of the demands and suggest applying the official doc- not add '' after the equals:>.